# ETCD warning The server needs to initialize the root user

Tags: etcd, etcd3, etcdctl

I have a simple `etcd` server running and I am using this github project called `etcd-keeper` to visualize the data in the `etcd`.

you can find the etcd-keeper project here: https://github.com/evildecay/etcdkeeper

I have created the `root` using `etcdctl` and everything works fine.

And I needed to create a another user that has limited view access. So, I created another `test-user` user and added `read-only` role with relevant persmissions.

Everything is good but, when I try to access the etcd server using `etcd-keeper` it **doesn't allow me to log in with the `test-user` credentials unless I signed in with `root` user first**

I don't need to share the root user credentials with the person logs with `test-user`. Otherwise no point in creating a new user noh.

I get this warning as below:

[image]

Can someone please help me to fix this problem? Is this error from `etcd` servr side? Anyone has used this `etcd-keeper` before?

Thank you.